# Putting formulas below each other in a block

Tags: beamer, block

I want the formulas `$2 \leq i \leq n$` and `$2 \leq i \leq n$, \hspace{5mm}, $n-i+3 \leq k \leq n$` in the slide below to start at the same point such that they are right below in the block. I've tried several things but none of them seem to work.

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Chain Ladder}
\begin{itemize}
\item relies on the assumption that expectations underlying columns and rows are      proportionalè
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=purple!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=black!20!white}
\begin{block}{developmentfactor}
$\hat{f_j} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-j+1} C_{ij}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-j+1}   C_{i,j-1}}$ \hspace{30mm} $2 \leq j \leq n$
\end{block}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=purple!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=black!20!white}
\vspace{5mm}
\item development factors applied to latest cumulative claim give forecasted future   value of cumulative claims
\begin{block}{estimated cumulative claim}
$\hat{C_{i,n-i+2}} = C_{i,n-i+1} \hat{f_{n-i+2}}$ \hspace{15mm} $2 \leq i \leq n$ \\ 
$\hat{C_{i,k}} = \hat{C_{i,k-1}} \hat{f_k}$ \hspace{15mm} $2 \leq i \leq n$,         \hspace{5mm}, $n-i+3 \leq k \leq n$

\end{block}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: You could use a display math approach: `\begin{align}\hat{C_{i,n-i+2}}  = ... \\ \hat{C_{i,k}} =  ...\end{align}` or two `\[ \]` blocks after one another. (Then of course you cannot break out of math mode for spaces, but there are math spaces such as `\quad` and friends.) Otherwise a `\nonindent` might help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I noticed that you've received answers to your questions and you haven't accepted any of them. You can accept answers that you consider solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to the left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just insert that as tabular material. Like this, you can align the content of the second block with the content of the first block as well:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{array}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=purple!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=black!20!white}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}[t]{Chain Ladder}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item relies on the assumption that expectations underlying columns and rows are proportionalè
        \begin{block}{development factor}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}p{5cm}<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
                \hat{f}_j = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-j+1} C_{ij}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-j+1}   C_{i,j-1}} &2 \leq j \leq n
            \end{tabular}   
        \end{block}     
        \baselineskip5mm
        \item development factors applied to latest cumulative claim give forecasted future value of cumulative claims
        \begin{block}{estimated cumulative claim}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}p{5cm}<{$}>{$}l<{$}}
                \hat{C}_{i,n-i+2} = C_{i,n-i+1} \hat{f}_{n-i+2} \hspace{15mm} &2 \leq i \leq n \\ 
                \hat{C}_{i,k} = \hat{C}_{i,k-1} \hat{f}_k &2 \leq i \leq n, \quad, n-i+3 \leq k \leq n
            \end{tabular}
        \end{block}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]